# dechex(4000) - Why is it not signed?

Tags: php

Why does PHP's `dechex(4000)` not return a signed hexadecimal value?

It returns:

```
fa0
```

As opposed to:

```
0xfa0
```

And is `signed` the correct term to use in describing this problem?  Or is there a better term to describe the `0x` portion?  Is that called a prefix?

Comment: dechex() returns unsigned hexadecimal values, that's clearly stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php). What _exactly_ is your question?

Comment: You should do some more research on what a signed and unsigned value is exactly. The reason this method returns `fa0` is because `0xfao` is not a valid hexadecimal number that its actually a string representation of `fa0` in order to make it clear that its a hexadecimal. Actually in either case its a string since the returned value is `Returns a string containing a hexadecimal representation of the given unsigned number argument.` its just made "print" this can be done by you if you want.

Comment: It's a lot easier for you to add `0x` to the start of a string when you need it than it is to remove it when you don't.

Comment: I suspect the OP was simply misusing the word "signed". The `0x` prefix can be thought of as a *sign* that the following digits are hexadecimal. The problem is that we almost universally use the word "signed" to refer to a postive-vs-negative indicator. See my answer for more discussion. I'm tempted to edit the question to use clearer terminology, but that would invalidate at least one of the existing answers. The real question being asked is *"Why does `dechex()` not add a `0x` prefix?"*

Answer (score 4):

This is not about signedness.

`fa0` and `0xfa0` represent the exact same number. However, without context, you probably wouldn't realize that the first represents a number in hexadecimal format. The `0x` prefix is just a hint for you (or the computer) that it represents a hexadecimal number.

As for why it doesn't: Why should it? It's not necessary. If you were to process it and already know it represents a hexadecimal number, you would just ignore the `0x` prefix. Thus, it may make processing slightly less cumbersome under some circumstances.

Signedness is about being able to represent both positive and negative values.

Comment: Additionally, no hexadecimal value is printed with the "0x" prefix in PHP (see eg. sprintf). http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Well for instance, in my other question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/185265/62307, I would want to generate those values myself but I can't because if i create a var with $b = dechex(4000), I don't get a signed variable

Comment: @Chud37 I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why do think you need to get a signed value?

Comment: @Chud37 Signed means that a numeric variable can represent both positive and negative numbers. It has absolutely nothing to do with the `0x` prefix, the fact that dechex() returns unsigned values is irrelevant to the fact that it doesn't return the (useless) `0x` prefix. Where did you read that `0x` hexadecimals are called "signed"? That's just wrong, and it's possibly the source of your confusion.

Comment: Thanks @YannisRizos, I am just trying to understand this whole deal.  It's all very new to me and I have no one to explain it.  I just did a search on 0x in Hex numbers and It told me that it was signed.  I did see negative and positives in there too, but I didnt understand it.

Comment: @YannisRizos Just wondering... do you think I should have emphasized more that the two things have nothing in common in my post? --- Chud: "it told me"? Where did it say that? Also, did you see my [**link**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/164240/10445) in the other comment for an explanation?

Comment: @phant0m Nah, your answer is good, Chud should spend sometime researching base systems (that other answer is also good ;) and signedness.

Answer (score 1):

I can see how you might refer to the `0x` prefix as a "sign". It *signifies* that the following digits are hexadecimal. But in programming, we almost universally use the word "sign" to refer to something that indicates whether a number is positive or negative. In a stored numeric value, there's usually one bit that indicates whether a number is negative. In program text, we can write `+42` to denote a positive integer and `-42` to denote a negative integer; the `+` or `-` character is the *sign*. (I'm glossing over some details regarding 2's-complement and other representations, and issues regarding `0`; also `+` and `-` are really operators, not part of the integer constants. Don't worry about that for now.)

So referring to anything other than a positive-or-negative indicator as a "sign" is bound to cause confusion. The `0x` in a hexadecimal literal like `0xfa0` can sensibly be referred to as a *prefix*, not as a "sign".

The name of PHP's `dechex` function, [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php), is actually a bit misleading. It takes an unsigned integer argument and returns a string containing the human-readable hexadecimal representation of that argument. The argument *is not decimal*; it's almost certainly stored in binary. We think of integers as decimal because we usually write them that way, but in fact integer values can be written in decimal, octal, hexadecimal, or as complicated expressions -- all of which result in a binary stored value. It doesn't convert *decimal* to hexadecimal; it converts a *number* to hexadecimal -- a number that *may* have resulted from the conversion of a decimal literal in the PHP source code to a stored binary integer.

As for why the result of `dechex()` doesn't include the `0x` prefix, the documentation doesn't say, but it's probably just because it's more convenient that way. If you want a string with a `0x` prefix, it's trivially easy to add it yourself (and to decide whether you want `0x` or `0X`). If `dechex()` returned a string with the prefix, and you didn't want it, you'd have to remove it.

This small program demonstrates these points:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    // Various arguments to dechex (decimal, octal, hexadecimal):
    echo "dechex(12345678)   = \"", dechex(12345678),   "\"\n";
    echo "dechex(012345678)  = \"", dechex(012345678),  "\"\n";
    echo "dechex(0xDEADBEEF) = \"", dechex(0xdeadbeef), "\"\n";
    echo "dechex(4*5)        = \"", dechex(4*5),        "\"\n";
    echo "With a prefix:       \"0x", dechex(4*5), "\"\n";
    // Another approach using sprintf():
    echo sprintf("0x%x", 1234), "\n";
    // ... or printf:
    printf("0X%X\n", 1234);
?>
```

Here's the output:

```
dechex(12345678)   = "bc614e"
dechex(012345678)  = "53977"
dechex(0xDEADBEEF) = "deadbeef"
dechex(4*5)        = "14"
With a prefix:       "0x14"
0x4d2
0X4D2
```

Comment: Might want to mention that number that starts with a '0' is interpreted as octal.  This is why `dechex(123) != dechex(0123)`

Comment: Also, you have to remember that PHP allows to to pass a string to `dechex()`, within which the number is in fact stored in decimal notation.

Comment: @MichaelT: I mentioned octal in a comment.

Comment: @phant0m: Interesting. I would have expected `dechex("0x123")` to return `"123"`, but it returns `"0"` -- and `dechex("0123")` returns `"7b"`, which is the hexadecimal representation of decimal `123`. I suppose it's a matter of how PHP does implicit conversions from strings to numbers?

Comment: Yes, apparently PHP converts it into an integer. If the string starts with a digit, it reads until the first non-digit is read (always assuming decimal notation). Otherwise, it's simply zero. That's why this `dechex("1e1");` evaluates to `1` but `dechex(0 + "1e1");` evaluates `a`, because when converting to a *number*, it also checks whether the strings contains an `e` or a `.` for floating-point conversions. I just wanted to give a thought as to why they might have named it `dechex` instead of `inthex` or something like that.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that when actually passing an int, `dechex` doesn't "see" whether it was represented in octal or hexadecimal or w/e.